# What is the correct format to add ActivityDate to Task object using SOAP api?

Tags: soap, tasks, activity

I have tried using moment object with different format, but none seems to be working. Can someone please suggest what is the correct format in which ActivityDate should be supplied to SOAP api of task creation.

API Name:
​​​​​​​/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Task

Comment: Salesforce uses YYYY-MM-DD for date fields.

Comment: @DavidCheng I tried using the same, but it is not filling up due date

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved, correct format is unix timestamp with miliseconds.